# is there a way to find that a paste operation is occured in my linux machine?

Tags: python, pyqt, pygtk, clipboard, xlib

I have used pygtk and could be able to trace every time a copy operation is done in my linux machine using clipboard owner-change. I'm not able to trace a paste event. So is there any way to find out the paste operation. Is there any events defined in pygtk, pyqt, xlib or in any other libraries in python. I'm trying for solution from so many days. Help with this if any one has solution or any idea

Comment: Did you come across [this blog on the subject](http://commonsmachinery.se/2013/07/copy-paste-linux/)? Don't know if it can help, but it includes some python scripts which do some low-level manipulations of the clipboard via xlib. This might at least tell you whether what you're trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about tracking paste operations of your own data, i.e. data that you set to the clipboard in your own application, then you could subclass [`QMimeData`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html) and reimplement `retreiveData()` (this should be feasible with pyqt, but I haven't tried).

Explanation: when you copy data from your application, the data is requested only at the moment the data is eventually pasted, so that you can provide many data formats without having to prepare all the data for all the formats beforehand. The idea is that you provide the data only when you know it will actually be needed. (Note: QMimeData provides setData() for convenience, and internally implements `retrieveData()` to return the data you set.)
You could probably use this fact to detect when your data has been pasted. (Although I haven't tried to implement this.)